# 301 redirecting in htaccess for redirecting url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect this please guide me

form

- `http://example.com/babycare/testimonials.php?id=7`

to

- `http://example.com/babycare/testimonial/cat/1`

Answer (score 1):

To redirect

- `http://example.com/babycare/testimonials.php?id=7`

to

- `http://example.com/babycare/testimonial/cat/1`

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/testimonials\.php\?id=([0-9]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /babycare/testimonial/cat/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: thanks it works fine but i also need this that is not working  from http://example.com/babycare/general_help/category.php?id=1  to http://example.com/babycare/article/category/1  thanks

Comment: In this when id is less than 10 it works fine but when id goes greater than 10 it goes always to id =1 i.e id=12 it went to id 1

Comment: The rule is applied when the value of id is exactly "7"  and doesnt match when the value of id is more/less then "7" .

Comment: i got it but when i change id in both RewriteCond to 10 and RewriteRule to 10 it goes to id 1. the probleam is that it only check that one rule is match it not check other .

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/testimonials\.php\?id=10  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /babycare/testimonial/cat/10? [L,R]  it not work it goes to id 1   i.e it goes here /babycare/testimonial/cate/1 and it should goes to babycare/testimonial/cate/10

Comment: Please tell me the solution i am wating @ starkeen

Comment: Ok,i have added a capture group to capture the value of id perameter dyanamically, the captured value is available for use in %1 variable , see the edit

Comment: thanks this is working  and can you please tell me how i redirect this                                                               from http://example.com/babycare/phone_package_detail.php#assessment             to    http://example.com/babycare/consultation/first_time                                     and                                                                                                     from http://example.com/babycare/phone_package_detail.php#package          to http://example.com/babycare/consultation/support_options